# Как свободно перемещать камеру в сцене редактора Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли сделать свободную камеру в редакторе Unity, чтобы беспрепятственно летать на WASD?

Зажимаю правую кнопку и появляется глазик, но я могу юзать только A и D...

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать пустой объект, на него повесить скрипт передвижения:

```
{
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float dirX, dirY;
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        dirY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, dirY * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Добавляем компонент CinemachineVirtualCamera (из пакета Cinemachine)
В нём нужно перетащить в поле Follow наш пустой объект.

Следом добавляем Rigidbody2D и ставим в поле bodytype значение kinematic.

P.s Вместо пустого объекта можно поставить любой спрайт